# Java SpringBoot REST POST , how to exclude integers

Tags: spring-boot, rest

Is there a way for me to prevent a user from logging in a number for POST request to a given field? The field variables are both String in java and varchar(255) in MySQL. I thought doing Integer.ParseInt and throwing a NumberException error when it catches it would bypass it, but trying the input again like this "name123", would let it come through again.

MySQL

```
`first_name` varchar(225) NOT NULL,
```

Java Code (Entity)

```
@Column(name="first_name")
private String firstName;
```

Java Code (Controller)

```
@PostMapping("/register")
public ClassName methodName(@RequestBody ClassName x){
    try{
      int check = Integer.parseInt(x.getfirstName())+1;
      throw new CustomException("Invalid first name");
      } catch (NumberFormatException ex){
          // doesn't do anything proceeds to processing 
          data below
      }

      ** rest of the code ** 
      return **
}
```

Test Case 1: Input= 1 --> Throws Custom Exception Message.

Test Case 2: Input= name123 --> Accepts it as first name.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can use regex to validate whether or not the input contains numbers

Comment: Not really good with regex, but with your idea I just decided to check each char of the POST and if it isDigit() throws new exception and it actually works. Thanks for the idea, I'll look further into it.

Comment: I would still go for a regex solution. Checking each char of a String is not the most solution in terms of performance. You can easily find online a regex to do what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely, `name123` accepted as valid input. But it's better to validate your string that does not contain any number and then throws an exception.

```java
 String firstName= getFirstName();

 if(firstName.matches(".*\\d.*")){
     // your input has number.
 }else{
    // valid input
 }
```